# I want to find element present in list and it compare with Enum value

Tags: spring, java-8

I have a List it has multiple object is present. for every object we have to find some string which compare to Enum value  How we get list of particular object

```
public enum ObjectType { 
CONTACT("Contact"), 
BANK_DETAILS("Bank-Details"), 
EMPLOYMENT("Employment"), 
PRODUCT("Product"),
 INCOME_DETAIL("Income-Details");
 ObjectType(String values) { this.values = values; } 
public String getValues() { return values; } 
private String values; }
```

for this i am using below method

```
List listOutput = errorsList.stream().
filter(e -> e.getObjType().contains(String.valueOf(ObjectType.values())))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it `return 0` value are present

Comment: Can you add more code ?  what is ObjectType ?

Comment: public enum ObjectType {
        CONTACT("Contact"),
        BANK_DETAILS("Bank-Details"), EMPLOYMENT("Employment"), 
        PRODUCT("Product"),  INCOME_DETAIL("Income-Details");
        ObjectType(String values) {
            this.values = values;
        }
        public String getValues() {
            return values;
        }
        private String values;
    }

Comment: What is `errorsList` and does it contain an attribute of `ObjectType`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adding check method to enum):

```
public enum ObjectType { 
  CONTACT("Contact"),
  BANK_DETAILS("Bank-Details"), 
  EMPLOYMENT("Employment"), 
  PRODUCT("Product"), 
  INCOME_DETAIL("Income-Details"); 

  private String values;

  ObjectType(String values) { 
      this.values = values; 
  } 

  public String getValues() { 
       return values; 
  } 

  public static boolean isValueExists(String test) {
      for (ObjectType o : ObjectType.values()) {
          if (o.getValues().equals(test)) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }

}
```

And then use it:

```
List listOutput = errorsList.stream().filter(e -> ObjectType.isValueExists(e.getObjType())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `isValueExists(e.getObjType())` incompatible types?

Comment: @nullpointer, as far as I understand from @priya code, `e.getObjType()` is not `ENUM` object, but `String`. I might be wrong though, more code examples needed in this case

Comment: Same point, the question doesn't seem to be clear at the first place.